# Jquery autocomplete not showing autocomplete dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a search input field - where when the user search for any string it will show up the autocomplete dropdown. But, for some reason it is not showing up the autocomplete dropdown. But when I locate my base url and end with /JobSearchItem.xhtml path in my address bar it will just return my json formatted result. But, it does not show any autocomplete dropdown. Can anyone check of how I can make my autocomplete to show. thanks. 
PS: Let me know if you guys need me to show any more code.

**Here is my code:**

```
     $(function() {


   var base_url = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";
    $( "#searchTextField" ).autocomplete({

         source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: base_url + "JobSearchItem.xhtml",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            q: request.searchValue
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map(data, function(v,i) { 
                    return { jobClassCD: v.jobClassCD, jobClassTitle: v.jobClassTitle }; 
                 }) 
            );
          }
        });


    });

  });
```

**json response**

```
    [{"jobClassCD":"1000","pGrade":"0","jobGroup":"","jobClassTitle":"ABC DEVELOPER"}
```

Comment: It looks like you use your inputs wrong in the function that needs to return the response.

Comment: in my  frontend search input, right?

Comment: this is my html input: `<input type="text" name="searchValue" id="searchTextField" class="form-control" placeholder="search"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do like this instead:

```
$(function() {
  var base_url = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";
  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + "JobSearchItem.xhtml",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      q: request.searchValue
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var newAray = $.map(data, function(v, i) {
        return {
          jobClassCD: v.jobClassCD,
          jobClassTitle: v.jobClassTitle
        };

        $("#searchTextField").autocomplete({
          source: newArray
        });
      });
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. But it did not work. Should I show you the json result when I go by with the address bar?

Comment: Do I need a "GET" parameters inside my jquery in order I can see my dropdown?

Comment: Please give me the json respond, and try my updated code. There can be a promise related issue that means you need to wait for the ajax response before you initialize the autocompiler.

Comment: Please check out my json response, in my updated question. Also, I tried the updated answer still not to show.

Comment: Because when I search with your updated code, in the console I am getting: `ReferenceError: request is not defined`

Comment: are you sure that autocompile can take an object as an input?

Comment: Sorry, but How can I check that to give you a answer?

Comment: Read the documentation, because I think that’s the problem here. In your map function you are returning an array of objects, and if you look at jQuery-autocompiles example it only takes an array as input.

Comment: and yes, I think I am sure that it takes an object as my input.

Comment: and also I have also instantiated a gson in my java code. Also, I have serialize the json target as `toJson`? Is it maybe thats the case?

Comment: Check out the source code here, and you will find a good example http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp